# Should I use a mutex when reading multiple files at the same time from different threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, filesystems

In the start sequence of my application/game, I load and decompress a large amount of files at the same time. To decrease startup time, this is done asynchronously in several threads, as the decompression algorithm is single-threaded.

Simplified example:

```
auto loadfile_f = [](std::filesystem::path p) -> image_t {
  auto raw_data = load_raw_file(p); // Multiple threads will access disc at the same time
  auto decompressed = decompress_data(raw_data);
  return decompressed;
};
auto futures = std::vector<std::future<image_t(std::filesystem::path)>>{};
for(auto&& path: paths) {
  futures.emplace_back(std::async(loadfile_f, path));
}
for(auto&& f: futures) { 
  f.wait(); 
}
```

Load function with mutex:

```
auto loadfile_f = [mutex_sptr = std::make_shared<std::mutex>()](std::filesystem::path p) mutable -> image_t {
  auto raw_data = std::vector<std::byte>{};
  {
    auto guard = std::lock_guard{*mutex};
    raw_data = load_raw_file(p); // Only one thread will access disc at the same time
  }
  auto decompressed = decompress_data(raw_data);
  return decompressed;
};
```

However, I'm thinking about using a mutex around the actual disc access. My idea is that reading multiple files at the same time would in most cases take more time as the file system would have to "swap context" while reading files (and then decompress them on each separate thread).

Should I use a mutex around the disc access, or do modern operating systems (windows/android/ios in my case) do this under the hood?

Comment: no need for a mutex unless the read function updates some shared global state.  Let the OS handle disk access.

Comment: It's not the general handling, I would like to know if this would reduce load times.

Comment: Your second example [shouldn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/41hescdKM). It requires copying a lambda that's non-copyable due to `std::mutex` member.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it by changing to a shared_ptr